# Material design lite navigation tabs autoslide

Tags: tabs, material-design, material-design-lite

I use this library https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/tabs to show "scrollables tabs".
My problem is when I select a tab which is under an arrow (right or left), the tab is well selected but we can't read all the word. On a native application, i saw that the tab bar scroll automatically to show the full selected tab.
Do you know a way to do this with that library ?

You can see a sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/fzngbjcw/2/

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>





    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header">
            <!-- Tabs -->
            <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                    <a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">My tab label 1</a>
                    <a href="#scroll-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 2</a>
                    <a href="#scroll-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 3</a>
                    <a href="#scroll-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 4</a>
                    <a href="#scroll-tab-5" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 5</a>
                    <a href="#scroll-tab-6" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 6</a>

            </div>
        </header>
        <main class="mdl-layout__content">


        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-1">
            <div class="page-content">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
            <div class="page-content">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-3">
            <div class="page-content">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-4">
            <div class="page-content">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-5">
            <div class="page-content">
            </div>
        </section>


        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-6">
            <div class="page-content">
            </div>
        </section>


    </main>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think [Material Design Lite](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite) has an auto-scrolling function for tabs that are outside the viewport (you may have seen that feature in a tabs demo for [Material Components for the web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) which is where the developers are now focused, having put MDL into "limited support").

That said, you can implement some simple auto-scrolling in MDL when a tab that is partially outside the viewport is clicked with some js to check whether the clicked tab is partially outside the viewport and then just triggering a click on the appropriate MDL scroll button (so you don't have to reinvent the scroll behavior). Just remember that MDL dynamically creates some of the html elements so you have to listen for the `mdl-componentupgraded` event before selecting those elements. Following is a working example:

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.mdl-layout__tab')
let left, right;

document.addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function(event) {
  left = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__tab-bar-left-button');
  right = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__tab-bar-right-button');
});

for (let tab of tabs) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let bounding = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (bounding.left < 0) {
      left.click();
    } else if (bounding.right > window.innerWidth) {
      right.click()
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">

      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">My tab label 1</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 2</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 3</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 4</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-5" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 5</a>
          <a href="#scroll-tab-6" class="mdl-layout__tab">My tabulation label 6</a>

        </div>
      </header>

      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-1">
          <div class="page-content">
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-2">
          <div class="page-content">
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-3">
          <div class="page-content">
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-4">
          <div class="page-content">
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-5">
          <div class="page-content">
          </div>
        </section>


        <section class="mdl-layout__tab-panel" id="scroll-tab-6">
          <div class="page-content">
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>

    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```